# How to set fields in DataRow object

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-5, datarow

I have migrated legacy code from vb to c#. The following migrated line of code raises an error:

```
using System.Data;
..
..
DataRow targetDataRow = targetDataTable.NewRow();
targetDataRow.SetField("DateValue", calendarRow.DateValue.ToShortDateString);
```

The error:

```
=Error  CS1061  'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'SetField' and no accessible extension method 'SetField' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I know I can use it like:

```
targetDataRow["DateValue"] = calendarRow.DateValue.ToShortDateString);
```

But, is this the best practice to set the value to a field in DataRow object?

Comment: Refactoring the `targetDataTable` into a typed `DataTable` would be better. Then you may set field value like this: `targetDataRow.DateValue = ...`. If you are migrating VB code it might be not a big extra work to accomplish this the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following migrated line of code raises an error:

```
 Error  CS1061  'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'SetField' and no accessible extension method 'SetField' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This error is because you're trying to use the [DataRowExtension.SetField Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.setfield?view=net-5.0) in which you don't have referenced in your project.

To add it, you can do so using the PM console:

```
 Install-Package System.Data.DataSetExtensions -Version 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02
```

> Is this the best practice to set the value to a field in DataRow object

It doesn't matter if you set it or call the method in this case. Under the hood [SetField](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,a820e1efcc3de63b) is doing the exact same thing and nothing more.